# RecyclerView adjust item height on scroll

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I want to change the height of first visible item of my RecyclerView by scroll event.
I can get the amount of vertical scroll (dy) but I don't know how to set it(dy) to the first visible item.

Can any1 help me?

Comment: Just don't even try to do that. It won't work. What do you want to do exactly? I might be able to suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: I wanna create a list like Chanel Fashion app - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chanel.fashion.public&hl=en

first item will be "expand" on scroll

Comment: Implement a custom `LayoutManager` for that. You can extend the `LinearLayoutManager` and additionally set the height of each item based on its position on the screen.

Comment: Can you install this app ?
When user scroll, item height will be adjusted.

Comment: Yes I know what you are talking about. As I said in my previous comment. Implement a custom `LayoutManager` based on the `LinearLayoutManager`. Shouldn't be difficult at all.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. thanks

Comment: Hey Hai, did you find out the way?